# What is the meaning of lemniscate related with clothing?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

[Here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Madonna_of_the_carnation_-_detail_of_lemniscate.jpg) is lemniscate is used as a part or feature of clothing. What doses it mean ?

TIA

Comment: Cool! New word, one that I would *never* have picked up on my own.

Comment: @medica And 'it pays to increase your word power', as the old Readers Digest used to say!

Comment: Always look up a good dictionary first.

Comment: @Kris Yes. I speak ironically. I don't think I ever remembered a single one of those Readers Digest words.

Answer (score 1):

[Lemniscate](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate): here refers to the ribbon shown in the picture.

In algebraic geometry, a lemniscate is any of several figure-eight or ∞-shaped curves. **The word comes from the Latin "lēmniscātus" meaning "decorated with ribbons", which in turn may come from the ancient Greek island of Lemnos where ribbons were worn as decorations,** or alternatively may refer to the wool from which the ribbons were made.

Source:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate

Comment: I note that it is named aster the Greek island of 'Lemnos'. One of its neighbours 'Lesbos', gave us *lesbian* Greek islands have had their influence!